# How to separate key value pairs and keep the key in a column and value in another column in angular using *ngFor?

Tags: html, typescript, angular10, angular-bootstrap

I have an object

```
obj = {
    a: 575
    b: 985
    c: 159
    d: 86
    e: 35
    f: 7
    }
```

I want to keep the `KEYS a, b, c, d, e, f`  in one column but different rows and the Values in corresponding rows in HTML using *ngFor.

How can I achieve that?

I tried:

```
<tr *ngFor = " let value of obj">
<td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

But not get the desired result.
I want the output as in the figure below:

[image]